# bootstrap-datepicker shows the wrong month (month select)

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using the [bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker) and I'm running in to this weird issue.

it works fine, but when I selects a month (E.g May) it shows the selected month as March. (2 months back), Always there is a 2 months gap between,
What is in the date select and months shown in the date-picker popup.

My date-picker is set to only show months and it starts from 1 Jan 2018,

and following is the config

```
 var date = new Date('January 1, 2018');
 $('.datepicker').datepicker({
      format: "MM yyyy",
      minViewMode: 'months',
      autoclose: true,
      startDate: date
 });
```

[image]

What seems to be going wrong here ?

Comment: Which version of the component are you using? Can you share a snippet/fiddle showing the issue? I can't reproduce the issue using v1.8.0

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({ 
  format: "MM yyyy",
  viewMode: "months", 
  minViewMode: "months",
  startDate: new Date('Jan 1, 2018')});
```

Try this out. This might help you

Comment: hi @Usar, thanks for the answer, but still the same issue ;(

Comment: This might work when i test it was working well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Although this might not help for your specific scenario, I did run into the same issue when I included the time.

So format of `dd/mm/yyyy` was doing fine but once I switched to `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm` it added 2 months (December instead of October).

All I eventually had to do was switch to the format `dd/mm/yyyy hh:ii` as shown in the [documentation](https://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/).

That saved me from switching to a [newer version](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) (which is still old when looking at it now, but the [github project of datetimepicker](https://github.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker) points to that link).